# Subquery with inner query referring to a different table than the outer query

Tags: sql, r, dplyr

How does one write a subquery with `dplyr` syntax where the inner query refers to a different table than the outer query?

Consider this example

```
library(DBI)
library(dplyr)

con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")

table1 <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,2,3),
  date = c("2019-01-04", "2019-01-04", "2019-01-05")
)

table2 <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,1,2,3),
  date = c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD")
)

dbWriteTable(con, "table1", table1, overwrite = T)
dbWriteTable(con, "table2", table2, overwrite = T)

dbGetQuery(con, "
SELECT * 
FROM table2
WHERE id in (
  SELECT id
  FROM table1
  WHERE date='2019-01-04'
)
")
```

One idea is to write the inner query first and then use the result in `filter()`. But this will not work with my real example because there are hundreds of thousands of matching ids and the database (MS SQL Server) throws an error when executing the second query.

```
ids <- con %>%
  tbl("table1") %>%
  filter(date == "2019-01-04") %>%
  pull(id)

con %>%
  tbl("table2") %>%
  filter(
    id %in% ids
  ) %>%
  show_query()

<SQL>
SELECT *
FROM `table2`
WHERE (`id` IN (1.0, 2.0)) # This is going to be a problem with a large number of matching ids
```

As far as I understand ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61745990/how-to-use-a-subquery-inside-dplyrfilter)), the way to write the subquery and execute it in the database is this

```
result <- con %>%
  tbl("table2") %>%
  filter(
    id %in% (
      con %>%
      tbl("table1") %>%
        filter(date == "2019-01-04") %>%
        pull(id)
    )
  )
```

This runs without error, but using `collect()` or `show_query()` on the `result` throws this error:

```
Error in `purrr::map_chr()`:
ℹ In index: 2.
Caused by error in `UseMethod()`:
! no applicable method for 'escape' applied to an object of class "c('SQLiteConnection', 'DBIConnection', 'DBIObject')"
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just use the `tbl(.)` references within an inner join.

```r
inner_join(tbl(con, "table1"), tbl(con, "table2"), by = "id") %>%
  filter(date.x == "2019-01-04") %>%
  select(id, date = date.y) %>%
  collect()
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#      id date 
#   <dbl> <chr>
# 1     1 AAA  
# 2     1 BBB  
# 3     2 CCC
```

It's still a "lazy" operation, as seen here:

```r
inner_join(tbl(con, "table1"), tbl(con, "table2"), by = "id") %>%
  filter(date.x == "2019-01-04") %>%
  select(id, date = date.y) %>%
  show_query()
# <SQL>
# SELECT `id`, `date.y` AS `date`
# FROM (
#   SELECT `LHS`.`id` AS `id`, `LHS`.`date` AS `date.x`, `RHS`.`date` AS `date.y`
#   FROM `table1` AS `LHS`
#   INNER JOIN `table2` AS `RHS`
#     ON (`LHS`.`id` = `RHS`.`id`)
# )
# WHERE (`date.x` = '2019-01-04')
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought this would be slow because looking at the generated SQL code it seems like the join is performed first and then the filter is applied (in my large table the filter selects a small fraction of the data). But it works just as fast as the SQL code with the subquery.

Comment: The optimization of SQL queries (done inside the server) is an opaque process for me, having never studied compilers or database-design. I understand some components but am frequently surprised by how well some obfuscated-queries perform. Glad it worked!